# execute function inside enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I'm trying to execute a function inside an enum, but when execute this code `ContentType.SaveContent("News")` i keep getting following error: `Use of instance member on type 'ContentType'; did you mean to use a value of type 'ContentType' instead?`. Why wont it run when i've set the type to String?

```
enum ContentType: String {

    case News = "News"
    case Card = "CardStack"

    func SaveContent(type: String) {
        switch type {
        case ContentType.News.rawValue:
            print("news")
        case ContentType.Card.rawValue:
            print("card")
        default:
            break
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this instead of what you are trying to do :
in ContentType Enum a func :

```
func saveContent() {
    switch self {
    case .News:
        print("news")
    case .Card:
        print("cards")
    }
}
```

in the other part of code that will use your enum :

```
func saveContentInClass(type: String) {
    guard let contentType = ContentType(rawValue: type) else {
        return
    }
    contentType.saveContent()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a `static func`, therefore you can only apply it to an instance of the type, not to the type itself, which is what you are trying to do. Add `static` before `func`.

...and, just for good style, don't give `func`s capital letters...